# writing a line in a text in a given sequence

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, replace

I have found some code and I changed it for my purpose. The code goes to the given line number and adds a new line with a certain format. But it does not work if I have a sequence of numbers. I could not find out why.

This is my code:

```
import fileinput

x = [2, 4, 5, 6]
for line in fileinput.FileInput("1.txt", inplace=1):
    print(line, end="")
    for index, item in enumerate(x):
        if line.startswith("ND "+str(x[index]-1)):
            print("ND "+str(x[index])+" 0 0 0 0")
```

This is the input file "1.txt":

```
ND 1 12 11 8 9
ND 3 15 11 7 9
ND 7 8  9  2 3
ND 8 4  5  1 12
ND 9 2  3  6 10
```

This is the result now :

```
ND 1 12 11 8 9
ND 2 0 0 0 0
ND 3 15 11 7 9
ND 4 0 0 0 0
ND 7 8  9  2 3
ND 8 4  5  1 12
ND 9 2  3  6 10
```

What I need should be like this:

```
ND 1 12 11 8 9
ND 2 0 0 0 0
ND 3 15 11 7 9
ND 4 0 0 0 0
ND 5 0 0 0 0
ND 6 0 0 0 0
ND 7 8  9  2 3
ND 8 4  5  1 12
ND 9 2  3  6 10
```

Can you please give me a hint! How should I change my code?

Comment: Your `x` is `given line numbers` and you want to print `ND x 0 0 0 0` at each line `x`, is that right?

Comment: @ Cà phê đen : yes thats right!

Comment: Your `x` list seems to be a list of missing line numbers `"ND *"` do you want to specify the list or would you rather it auto fill if a line is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like that work for you ? (you don't need to maintain the list of missing lines in `x`). It's not the most elegant code but it can be improved later if that work for you.

```
import fileinput

n = 1
for line in fileinput.FileInput("1.txt", inplace=1):
    while not line.startswith("ND %d" % n):
        print("ND %d 0 0 0 0" % n)
        n+=1
    print(line)
    n+=1
```

Comment: Here it needs a break, otherwise it cannot stop and writes lines i.e.            ND 8888 0 0 0 0 ... and so on. I add a if and break to stop it and works very good.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ND 4` and `ND 5` lines in your `1.txt`. That's why you cannot print the `ND 5 0 0 0 0` and `ND 6 0 0 0 0`.

You can use the regex to extract line number from text and compare:

```
import fileinput
import re

x = [2, 4, 5, 6]
last = 0
for line in fileinput.FileInput("1.txt", inplace=1):
    # using regex to extract the "current" line number from ND...
    current = int(re.search(r'\d+', line).group())
    for index, item in enumerate(x):
        # "=" because there's a case that your given line already exists
        if item > last and item <= current:
            print("ND "+str(item)+" 0 0 0 0")
    last = current 
print(line, end="")
```

Comment: It destroys the original 1.txt and overwrites it with the 4 new lines.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, it needs a break with the maximum number of ND in the file. So in this case at n == 10.

```
n = 1
for line in fileinput.FileInput("1.txt", inplace=1):
    while not line.startswith("ND %d" % n):
        print("ND %d 0 0 0 0" % n)
        n+=1
        if n == 10:
            break
    print(line, end="")
    n+=1
```